# Globally remove and selectively add tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Our product owners would like the tabbing between elements on the page to be more useful. Currently, when you tab through items, you are also tabbing through things that can have focus like text links. I really don't want to add `tabIndex` to every element if I can help it.

I'd like to know if there's a way to:

1. Global remove all tab indexes (like setting it to `tabindex="-1"`) except for elements that should always be tabbed through like textboxes, checkmarks, and radio buttons.
2. Selectively add or remove the tab index to individual elements that are exceptions to the rule above.

I'm fine having all the tab-able elements share the same index like `tabindex="0"` so the browser determines the actual order.

I'm using Angular and have JQuery as well, but ideally would like this to be a CSS-only thing if that is possible.

Comment: "*Currently, when [users] tab through items, [they] are also tabbing through things that can have focus like text links.*" - it seems that your product owners are aiming to discriminate against those that use the keyboard for interaction with your, or their, site. *Why?*

Comment: @DavidThomas, actually just the opposite. They are trying to streamline the tabbing functionality so you don't have to tab through a number of elements that are not required to perform the particular business function they are trying to accomplish. This is an internal web application to support business processes.

Comment: But that appears to necessarily prevent a subset of users from being able to use a keyboard to interact with the 'not required' "*text link*" elements? If they're not relevant, why would they be present in the document? I realise my understanding is limited to only the text of this question (and comments), but it still feels like those that choose to not use a mouse are being prevented from using the entirety of the site.

Comment: @DavidThomas, one example might be a wizard that has a form for the user to fill out but also a div with infinite scrolling that has content they can use for reference. The primary function they are trying to accomplish is to fill out the wizard form, but if they have to tab through a thousand items in a list to get down to the "Continue" button, then using only their keyboard becomes too difficult. I understand you are probably referring to people with accessibility needs, but like I said, this is a non-public facing tool they built support a business function and it's ultimately their call.

Comment: @DavidThomas, now that I think about it, it might be possible to do both. If, instead of setting `tabindex="-1"` for elements that are less important, we set them all to `tabindex="1"`, then the user would be able to tab through all the elements that are important to the business function first (with `tabindex="0"`), but they could continue to tab through the rest of the page if the choose to.